# Construction of a 1-1 correspondence from $(-1, 1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

Is there any function that is a 1-1 correspondence from the interval $(-1,1)$ to the set of all reals? Consider the additional caveat that the said function must also be differentiable.

Answer (score 5):

Yes; forget mere differentiability, there's a *smooth* one! Consider an appropriate transformation of the function $x \mapsto \tan x$.

Answer (score 3):

Forget mere smoothness, there's a *rational* one:
$x\mapsto \frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{1+x}$.

Comment: Nicely done ;) +1

Comment: Thanks, just thought I'd add it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Forget mere rationalness, there's a linear one: $x \mapsto 10^{80}x$. Doesn't really work but who's going to notice? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
f : (-1,1)&\to\Bbb{R}\\
x&\mapsto\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: wouldn't it be tan(pi*x/2) ?

Comment: whups, my bad. Being silly